# expire redis cache key at particular hours rather than duration

Tags: node.js, redis

My code is as shown below:

```
client.set(name, data, 'EX', 23 * 60 * 60, (err, reply) => {

        });
```

What it does is , it stores the key-value for 23 hours. But is there any way , through which I can set the key to expire at 11:59 p.m. in the night?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis itself doesn't provide this functionality. But you can calculate the value of seconds until midnight.

```
var nd = new Date().setHours(23,59,59);
var expire = Math.floor((nd-Date.now())/1000);
```

Comment: Should write `expire` value that you gave instead of `23*60*60` in my method or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, instead of 23*60*60

Comment: I fixed expression a bit.

Comment: Redis itself **does** provide it - the answer is legit otherwise.

Comment: @ItamarHaber my bad, there is `EXPIREAT`, but it will be two commands instead of one.

Comment: @Imaskar yep, that's why I felt obliged to add my answer ;)

Answer (score 9):

Despite the accepted answer, you could use [`EXPIREAT`](https://redis.io/commands/expireat) for that. However, since `SET` does not support this as an argument, you'll need two calls in your code.

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: @for_stack why? 3 math operations + system clock call is about 50ns, another call to Redis is ~20mcs.

Comment: @Imaskar I'll explain the comment in details: 1. Redis has a built-in command to do the job, and no need to do the math by yourself. 2. Your answer is also good, but it relies on time-synchronization. All clients should have consistent time clock with the server. Otherwise, you might set an incorrect expiration. 3. If you do care another extra call, and need the operations to be atomic, you can use Lua script to improve the performance.