# How to make redis expire at an exact time in java?

Tags: java, redis

example: I want make redis string "aKey":"aValue"  expired at a future time(2018.08.17 00:00, now is 2018.08.16 12:00),
this is my solution:

```
long expireTime = Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().with(LocalTime.MAX).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()).getTime() - Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()).getTime();
redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("aKey","aValue",expireTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I want a perfect solution.

Comment: **perfect solution** what's the problem of your solution?

Comment: i think it not the best the way to solve it;

Comment: Well there are some logical components you need, in order to put a TTL on a message. The first is the current time and the second is the time you would like it to expire, which you have got. My only recommendation would be to move that logic into an appropriately named method (`getExpiry`).

Comment: You need `EXPIREAT`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51131212/expire-redis-cache-key-at-particular-hours-rather-than-duration/51137153#51137153)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for your help, I got it. Redis has an "EXPIREAT" command, which can be used like this in Java:

```
redisTemplate.opsForValue().set("aKey","aValue");
redisTemplate.expireAt("aKey",Date.from(LocalDateTime.now().with(LocalTime.MAX).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
```